# Rails - script/server boot up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Can someone help me out with something seemingly simple? My newness to Ruby on Rails is the reason, no doubt. I cannot start up the server. It looks like the boot file cannot be located but I'm nor sure at all.

There are several versions of ruby here, related to installing rvm:

which -a ruby
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
/Users/me/.rvm/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

Probably need to remove some?

Using Rails 3.2.9 with Ruby 1.9.3 on a Mac Mini

Thanks!

cd [rails project dir]

$ script/server

/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 
cannot load such file -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)

from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'

from script/server:2:in `'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the issue you are getting. script/server still works, what you are experiencing is an issue with the gems you are trying to use. What you might try is running rails s --trace, see what gems are causing the issue and manually reinstalling them. From the looks of it, it's just an issue with a lone gem with dependencies in 1.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

With Rails 3+ you get access to the rails command line scripts so instead of calling `script/server` you just run `rails server` or `rails s` for short.